# Python - functional "find"?

Tags: python, functional-programming, lambda

I need a function, which is capable of iterating over the collection, calling a supplied function with element of the collection as a parameter and returning the parameter or it's index when received "True" from supplied function.

It is somethong like this:

```
def find(f, seq, index_only=True, item_only=False):
     """Return first item in sequence where f(item) == True."""
     index = 0
     for item in seq:
         if f(item):
             if index_only:
                 return index
             if item_only:
                 return item
             return index, item
         index+= 1
     raise KeyError
```

So I am wondering whether there's anything like that in standart python toolset?

Comment: The OP's snippet is the more direct (if only a bit longer) way to express the requirement; it may well be the prescribed way, depending on the situation.  From the responses, however, comes a very useful insight: `regarding loops, when in doubt, consult/consider itertools`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.dropwhile` to skip over the items for which the supplied function returns `False`, then take the first item of the rest (if any). If you need the index rather than the item, incorporate `enumerate` from the Recipes section of [`itertools` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html).

To reverse truth values returned by the supplied function, use a `lambda` (`lambda x: not pred (x)`, where `pred` is the supplied function) or a named wrapper:

```
def negate(f):
    def wrapped(x):
        return not f(x)
    return wrapped
```

Example:

```
def odd(x): return x % 2 == 1
itertools.dropwhile(negate(odd), [2,4,1]).next()
# => 1
```

This will throw `StopIteration` if no matching item is found; wrap it in a function of your own to throw an exception of your choice instead.

Comment: :( I think OP's question is itself the answer, this may be bit more for simple iteration.

Comment: I agree with Anurag, but if `itertools` were used I think `ifilter` would be simpler. 
Ex: `itertools.ifilter(odd, [2,4,1]).next()`

Comment: I'm inclined to agree about the `ifilter`. Also, the OP's snippet does indeed solve the basic problem just fine; still, wondering what's there in the standard lib to help avoid writing code for stuff like this seems pretty reasonable. I'd say mjv's comment on the question sums up the important lesson here perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Try [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) and for example [ifilter](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is any such function with such exact semantics, and anyway your function is short , good enough and you can easily improve it for later use, so use it.

because simple is better than complex.